# (Flutter) How can I identify which ListTile in my ListView the user clicked the PopupMenuItem?

Tags: flutter-web, popupmenu

I have a ListView which holds ListTiles. Each tile represents a user of my users array. The trailing of a tile is a PopupMenuButton. When the user clicks on one PopupMenuItem, a function shall be called. So far so good. In the "onSelected" I would like to pass data of the corresponding user to a function.

Could anybody please give me a hint, how I should change the code to be able to do so?

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserListMobilePortrait extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> users;
  const UserListMobilePortrait({
    Key key,
    this.users,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final HttpsCallable setRoleCallable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'setRoles')
          ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
          
    final button = new PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
              new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: const Text('Make Admin'), value: 'admin'),
              new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: const Text('Make Editor'), value: 'editor'),
            ],
        onSelected: (selectedItem) async {
          try {
            final HttpsCallableResult result = await setRoleCallable.call(
              <String, dynamic>{
                //'user' shall represent the user of the clicked ListTile, but how to pass it?
                'email': user.data()['email'],
                'role': selectedItem,
                'permission': 'grant'
              },
            );
            print(result.data);
          } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
            print('caught firebase functions exception');
            print(e.code);
            print(e.message);
            print(e.details);
          } catch (e) {
            print('caught generic exception');
            print(e);
          }
        });

    return ListView(
      children: users
          .map((user) => ListTile(
                title: Text(
                    (user.data()['email'] != null) ? user.data()['email'] : ""),
                subtitle: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text((user.data()['displayName'] != null)
                        ? user.data()['displayName']
                        : ""),
                    Container(
                      width: 6,
                    ),
                    user.data()['isAdmin'] == true
                        ? Chip(
                            label: Text('admin'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.orange[600],
                            shadowColor: Colors.orange[900],
                          )
                        : Text(''),
                    Container(
                      width: 6,
                    ),
                    user.data()['isEditor'] == true
                        ? Chip(
                            label: Text('editor'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blue[600],
                            shadowColor: Colors.blue[900],
                          )
                        : Text(''),
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: button,
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

understanding your problem a simple workaround will be to use a Listview Builder(And also using a ListView Builder will optmize the app for speed)

```
 const List = ["Hello", "World", "Temp"]
 ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      //return (Your widget [a list tile preferably and use onTap(and access the index 
  in the function)])
        return(ListTile(onTap:(){
        print(List[index]);
        //you can access the index and use the main list to get its following data
   };       
};
```

This will workout :)

Comment: Thanks so far, but how would the call for "button" look like? How to get the index in there or do I have do setup a callback in this case?

Comment: No not needed, the itemBuilder will give you the index, you can directly access the data that was stored in the list with that index,

Comment: Sure. Did you notice how I create the trailing of the ListTile? How should "button" get to know my index?

Comment: you can access that index that the ITEMBUILDER gives you in its local scope, in any area, just add a onTap(), and you will have the index from the ITEMBUILDER, and if you see my example, i have a list above that is the reference, so once you have the index returning from the ITEMBUILDER, you can use it and reference it and have all the data you need ....

Answer (score 0):

My solution was moving the former final button to its own class. So I can pass the data to the constructor.

UserPopupMenuButton

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserPopupMenuButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final QueryDocumentSnapshot user;
  const UserPopupMenuButton({
    Key key,
    this.user,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final HttpsCallable setRoleCallable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'setRoles')
          ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
    return PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
              new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: const Text('Make Admin'), value: 'admin'),
              new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: const Text('Make Editor'), value: 'editor'),
            ],
        onSelected: (selectedItem) async {
          try {
            final HttpsCallableResult result = await setRoleCallable.call(
              <String, dynamic>{
                'email': user.data()['email'],
                'role': selectedItem,
                'permission': 'grant'
              },
            );
            print(result.data);
          } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
            print('caught firebase functions exception');
            print(e.code);
            print(e.message);
            print(e.details);
          } catch (e) {
            print('caught generic exception');
            print(e);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

And using it as the trailing for the ListTile:

```dart
trailing: UserPopupMenuButton(user: user),
```